# query on the time varying linear quadratic regulator

Tags: drake

I saw a `linear_quadratic_regulator.h` includes infinite horizon fixed point LQR. I am wondering if there is a LQR for finite horizon optimal tracking. I saw some information about `tvlqr` on the [website](http://drake.mit.edu/), but is there any news on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, I'm afraid, but it's coming very soon.
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/9013

- Russ